# Cyclic dependency in 2 different projects in Maven

Tags: java, maven

Maven ProjectA has ProjectB as dependency.
Now ProjectB needs one class from ProjectA . So ProjectB also needs ProjectA as dependency.

Unfortunately this gives cyclic dependeny error in Maven. It is not allowed.

So my solution. Outsource this 1 needed class to an own project and include it to ProjectA and ProjectB.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you either need an additional project, or you need to merge both projects into one.

If you opt for three projects, it might be better to create a multi-module project.

Comment: Is there a way to get rid of cyclic dependeny with factory pattern ??

Comment: Could you be more explicit about what you have in mind?